# When should Redirect be called in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My react component should work as follows:

1. Check a global variable for error and if there is error redirect to home and unset the global error variable.
2. Otherwise it should render a  which will use current page's location to redirect to correct location.

How should I go about doing this. The only way which somehow works is if I do conditional render and set global variable in render. Is there any better way?

Comment: do you consider to use react-router-dom they have redirect and they explain to you how to build private route that with only the access you give they can access this route

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm using `context api` to share the `state` across all `routes` available.

1. For question **No. 1** - use `protected route`. (Much simpler & neat)

- **predeclared** `path` & `component` on `<ProtectedRoute path="/anyPath" component={anyComponent}/>`
- if you want to have flexibility on setting the `path` yourself, then go to **methods** **No. 2** below
- in `App.js`:-

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ErrorState } from "./contexts/ErrorState";
// import ProtectedRoute from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRoute";
import ProtectedRouteCustom from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRouteCustom";
import Home from "./comps/Home";
import Demo from "./comps/Demo";
import Dashboard from "./comps/Dashboard";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorState>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Demo exact path="/demo" component={Demo} />
          {/*} <ProtectedRoute exact path="/demo/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
          <ProtectedRouteCustom path="/demo" />
          <Route path="*" component={() => "Not Found"} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ErrorState>
  );
}
```

- `ProtectedRoute.js` (emphasis more on `Route` `render`):-

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useError } from "../../contexts/ErrorState";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [errorState, errorDispatch] = useError();
  const { error } = errorState;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        // you can use props.location.pathname to redirect user to the route path you have specified in App.js (see in console.log)
        console.log(props);
        // render Dashboard component if 'error' === false
        if (!error) return <Component {...props} />;
        // redirect to homepage if error === false
        else
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                // specify the path to redirect (if condition 'error' === true)
                pathname: "/",
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

2. For question **No. 2** - you can build your own **custom** `protected route`

- `path` can be specified or set it yourself in `ProtectedRouteCustom`
- `App.js`:-

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ErrorState } from "./contexts/ErrorState";
// import ProtectedRoute from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRoute";
import ProtectedRouteCustom from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRouteCustom";
import Home from "./comps/Home";
import Demo from "./comps/Demo";
import Dashboard from "./comps/Dashboard";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorState>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Demo exact path="/demo" component={Demo} />
          {/*} <ProtectedRoute exact path="/demo/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
          <ProtectedRouteCustom path="/demo" />
          <Route path="*" component={() => "Not Found"} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ErrorState>
  );
}
```

- **custom** `protected route`:- (emphasis more on `Redirect` rather than `Route` `render`)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useError } from "../../contexts/ErrorState";
import Dashboard from "../Dashboard";

const ProtectedRouteCustom = ({ path }) => {
  const [errorState, errorDispatch] = useError();
  const { error } = errorState;

  return (
    <>
      {error ? (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Redirect from={path} to={path + "/dashboard"} />
          <Route to={path + "/dashboard"} component={Dashboard} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRouteCustom;
```

You can see the [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1zdzjo?file=src%2FApp.js) here for full working code.

Guidelines on how to use the **sandbox** code

1. Environment for **No. 1**:-

- uncomment/enable:

  - `import ProtectedRoute from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRoute";`
  - `<ProtectedRoute exact path="/demo/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />`
- comment/disable:

  - `import ProtectedRouteCondition from "./comps/routes/ProtectedRouteCondition";`
  - `<ProtectedRouteCondition path="/demo" />`

2. Environment for **No. 2**: *run as it is*

Answer (score -1):

Generally all coder using your methods. If you checking React in Facebook Group. You can find correct answer ı think.